# Python 2: calculator design - how do a loop for regex .group position?

Tags: python, regex, loops

I'm new to programming and python2... my assignment is on making a calculator that allows for multiple addition/substraction/multiplication/division.

so for example, if user input 3+9-4, my calculator should calculate as 3+9-4 = 12-4=8 in that sequence. (don't have to show the working though, end result only)

I have defined my functions for operations. my function is always operation of two variable. one example as such:

```
def addition(x, y):
    return x + y
```

so I have defined also for my subtraction, multiplication and division. all are 2-variables- function.

now I got my regex part... And i think my regex is inclusive of users' repetition of operation sign and the number that follows..

```
num_pattern = r"(-?[\d]+\.?[\d]*) ?(([+\-*/=]) ?(-?[\d]+\.?[\d]*))+"
num_match = re.match(num_pattern, user_input)
```

And what I want to do next is to do a loop such that after calculating 3+9, the program will put 12 back into the number pattern and continue to do 12-4 and gives me the final result.

and I got really stuck...

Of course, the part below doesn't work. but just to show my thought...:

[image]

`handle_operation` is my function that put all operations in one function for leaning purpose... var1 is my first variable --> x  var2 is my second variable --> y. op is my operator sign [+-*/]

why x+5 is because if I only have 2+3 for example, my string returned will contain group(0), group(1), group(2), group(3), group(4) --> 5 items. so I supposed if the trend continues, my new first item would be the 6th...

so first question: x+=5 contains syntax error.. what's not right here? 
second: can I assign my string positions in a loop like that in the first place?
third:  how exactly should I do this? Or my pattern wasn't right in the first place?

Thanks.

Comment: `x += 5` is valid syntax, however the line before doesn't have a closing parenthesis.

Comment: ah! yes, that's quite stupid. thanks. :) But regarding the loop, how to do it? or is there better way to do it?

Comment: ok. i think this question is too long... and i'd like to break it down by step. So the first part is: num_pattern = r"(-?[\d]+\.?[\d]*) ?(([+\-*/=]+) ?(-?[\d]+\.?[\d]*))+"   ==> if the user input: 1+ 2 + 3 +4, and if i use .findall, should i see all numbers and signs there? but the result shows that i only have 6 items in the list. Why is that so?